Expression for intensity in quantum vs. classical electromagnetics
I am wondering how the following expression for intensity in terms of the quantized fields is derived:
$$ I = \frac{2\epsilon_0 c}{P} \int_0^P \langle E^-(t) E^+ (t) \rangle dt $$
where $P$ is the period of the wave.
Can this be derived starting from the following classical expression for intensity? $$I = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{\mu}} |E|^2 $$
Also if anyone can suggest any good references, that'd be great!
